# Unknown column 'Project2.Name' in 'where clause'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple statement to get data from my mySQL database but it get the following error:

> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'Project2.Name' in 'where
>   clause']    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +272
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId) +68
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&
>   affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force) +110    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>   +761    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +1557
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +33
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   +12    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +435

The Statement:

```
using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
{
    var Result = ctx.Items.Where(x => x.Contact.Country == Country)
                .GroupBy(p => p.Name).Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.Value == "X"))

                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).FirstOrDefault()) //<- Error
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()) // <- no Error

                .ToList();
}
```

When I use the first `Select` I get this error, with the second, the code is working fine. Anyone knows the reason?

Same Error found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174418/1315444)

I'm using .NET Connector 6.7.4 so it [can't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-6-7-4.html) be bug [#68513](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68513)

Comment: That looks awful, too. Why exactly are you Ordering in a Grouping?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I need the newest one

Comment: It actually looks like the error is occurring at `.GroupBy(p => p.Name)` to me.

Comment: Could you please send the model (Item and Content classes, mapping and context)?

Comment: PS: looking other issues similar to this, it looks like a bug of the EF provider that generates a wrong HAVING clause

Comment: Please show us the SQL code generated.

Comment: @fubo Why I have a feeling I've already seen that query. Or it was another MySQL provider bug. It really doesn't matter what # the bug is, the most important is that it definitely is a bug, so I don't know what are you expecting here.

Comment: @IvanStoev if it's a bug i expect at least a bug number which i couldnt find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let see. You have a perfectly valid LINQ to Entities query, it works with SqlServer provider and does not work with MySQL provider. Sounds like a MySQL provider bug to me, what else it could be? But which one? I don't see how that helps, but put my bet on [#78610](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78610)(initiated by [ASP MVC MsSql to MySQL migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790571/asp-mvc-mssql-to-mysql-migration) SO post), marked as duplicate of [#76663](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76663). Or [#77543](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77543) etc.

So MySQL connector has issues with `OrderBy` in subqueries. As a workaround, I could suggest (when possible) the alternative way of implementing `MaxBy`, i.e. (in pseudo code) instead of `seq.OrderByDescending(col).FirstOrDefault()` use the `seq.FirstOrDefault(col == seq.Max(col))` pattern which works:

```
var Result = ctx.Items
    .Where(x => x.Contact.Country == Country)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(x => x.Value == "X"))
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Date == g.Max(e1 => e1.Date)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort before grouping.  The query providers can only translate a limited amount of expression trees and the way you have it apparently is one of them.  Sorting first will have equivalent behavior.

```
var query = ctx.Items
    .Where(x => x.Contact.Country == Country)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(x => x.Value == "X"))
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Actually sort before grouping is ignored by query providers, so although the above does not generate exception, I doubt it returns the intended result. The issue is specific to MySQL provider (bug) - the original query works w/o problem with SqlServer for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the SQL that the code generates, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/3572241 and other answers to that question.

Then try running the SQL in mysql to isolate the problem.

Comment: To capture the query you can remove the ToList() and just point the mouse on the object.